# Gitlab: importing by repo url from old instance to new instance not working

Tags: gitlab

I have old self-hosted gitlab instance (Version 8.13.6). Now we've new self hosted gitlab instance (Version 15.2) in different server.

I need to import projects from the old instance to new instance. For this I am using  "Repository by URL".  But it doesn't seem to work, whenever I enter project URL from old instance, I also tried to supply valid login credentials for old instance, I get following error -

> There is not a valid Git repository at this URL. If your HTTP
> repository is not publicly accessible, verify your credentials.

The project in old instance is not publicly accessible. User needs to login to access the project.

Is there anyway to import my projects from old instance to the new one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the error message:

> There is not a valid Git repository at this URL. If your HTTP repository is not publicly accessible, verify your credentials.

Hence the problem is with the access.

1. Check if the network is an issue, i.e., can you access the old 8.13.6 instance from your 15.2 instance.
2. If the network is not an issue, then the issue usually lies on the credential, if the project on the old instance is not publicly available, you can either:

   - 2.1 Make it publicly available by turning that project into a public one before using "Repository by URL"
   - 2.2 When you use "Repository by URL", be sure to input your username and password into the correct place. Then GitLab will know it.
     [image: username and password]
   - 2.3 If supplying username and password won't work, you may try to supply them in this form in your Git repository URL: `https://username:password@yourgitlaburl.com/group/project.git`

Comment: the last option (2.3) seems to work. Thanks

Comment: I have many repos in my old instance, importing them one by one is not possible, is it possible to import them in bulk using option 2.3 you mentioned? Thanks

Comment: That is another question then. Though you may check out Congregate https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/index.html#automate-group-and-project-import

Answer (score 1):

You stated that the old and new instances are on the same network, so they can access each other.

You have to remember that the **Repository by URL** feature allows you to enter the credentials, which have to be the **old server credentials**.

Please check it and try again...

Comment: Sorry if I am not clear, both of them are in different network and different URLs. I also mentioned I tried to enter credentials to old instance, but still same error. Thanks

Comment: Can the new host reach the old one? Maybe a networking issue.